# ReferenceError: Client Missing Intents Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**I've just started working on a discord bot, but whenever I try to start it using node . in the cmd prompt, I get this error;**

```
C:\Users\kaute\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos De Programação\NewBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\kaute\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos De Programação\NewBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:548:13)
    at new Client (C:\Users\kaute\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos De Programação\NewBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kaute\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Projetos De Programação\NewBot\src\main.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

**I've looked around and cant find anything specific enough to fix my issue. Here is my code;**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = The Token;

bot.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('The bot is ready!')
});
```

**As I said I just started today, so There isn't much here**

Comment: discord.js v13 requires you to provide intents.

Comment: You should also read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

Since `discord.js` v13, you need to provide intents when declaring the client. They were introduced so that developers could choose which events their bot needed to receive based on which data it needs to function. To add intents to your client, you can import `Intents` from `discord.js` and then add it to the client by using:

```js
const { Intents, Client } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
})
```

To learn more about intents, you can go to => [Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for helping, I really didn't know I needed to import the INTENTS. Thanks bro.